# How to use Netbeans Formatter in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

I am working within a development team that uses Netbeans as standard-IDE. I want to switch to IntelliJ without actually influencing the code formatting compared to Netbeans.
So is there a way to make IntelliJ format the code exactly the same as Netbeans does? e.g. something like EclipseFormatter-Plugin does when using  Netbeans in an Eclipse team?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use EclipseFormatter in both IDEs. Otherwise no, unless you create a NetbeansFormatter plugin.

Comment: Do you use git? Then just dont care about the settings and put the .idea folder in .gitignore file

Comment: The .idea folder has nothing to do with your (re-)formatted source code.